# Lie Bracket of vector fields

Tags: general-topology, multivariable-calculus, differential-geometry, differential-topology

I would like to show that the following identity holds:

> $$\frac{d}{dt}\Bigr|_{t=t_0} d\phi_{-t}^X(\phi_t^X(m))Y(\phi_t^X(m))=d\phi_{-t_0}^X(\phi_{t_0}^X(m))[X,Y](\phi_{t_0}^X(m)),$$
> $\phi_t^X(m)$ is the flow of the smooth vector field $X$, given by: $\frac{d}{dt}\phi_t^X(m)=X(\phi_t^X(m)), \quad  \phi_0^X(m)=m.$ And the Lie bracket $[X,Y]$ is given by:$[X,Y](m)=dY(m)X(m)-dX(m)Y(m)$.

**My try:**

I use the fact that (provided as a hint): **$d\phi_{-t}^X(\phi_t^X(m))=(d\phi_t^X(m))^{-1}$** and additionally for a matrix $\dot {A(t)^{-1}}=-A(t)^{-1} \dot A(t) A(t)^{-1} $, $\dot{(\space)}=\frac{d}{dt}$ :

$$\frac{d}{dt}\Bigr|_{t=t_0} d\phi_{-t}^X(\phi_t^X(m))Y(\phi_t^X(m))=\frac{d}{dt}\Bigr|_{t=t_0} (d\phi_t^X(m))^{-1}Y(\phi_t^X(m))=$$
$$-(d\phi_{t_0}^X(m))^{-1}(\frac{d}{dt}\Bigr|_{t=t_0}d\phi_t^X(m))(d\phi_{t_0}^X(m))^{-1}Y(\phi_{t_0}^X(m))+ $$
$$(d\phi_{t_0}^X(m))^{-1}dY(\phi_{t_0}^X(m))\frac{d}{dt}\Bigr|_{t=t_0}\phi_t^X(m)=$$

$$\text{Now I use:}$$

$$\frac{d}{dt}\Bigr|_{t=t_0} \phi_t^X(m)=X(\phi_{t_0}^X(m));$$
$$\frac{d}{dt}\Bigr|_{t=t_0} d\phi_t^X(m)=dX(\phi_{t_0}^X(m)).$$
$$=(d\phi_{t_0}^X(m))^{-1} \bigg[-dX(\phi_{t_0}^X(m))\color{red}{(d\phi_{t_0}^X(m))^{-1}Y(\phi_{t_0}^X(m))}+dY(\phi_{t_0}^X(m))X(\phi_{t_0}^X(m))\bigg ].$$

This is almost correct but the red part screws it up. Could someone please help me with this, I can't seem to be able to solve it.

**EDIT:** (Using the comments from @Ted Shifrin below, I've come up with this)

We have: $\frac{d}{dt}\Bigr|_{t=t_0} (d\phi_t^X(m))^{-1}Y (\phi_t^X(m))=$

$$\text{Let's suppose I take a new variable } \tilde{t}=t-t_0,$$
$$\text{this should hold: } \frac{d}{dt}\Bigr|_{t=t_0}=\frac{d}{d\tilde{t}}\Bigr|_{\tilde{t}=0}.$$
$$\text{Using this and } \color{red}{d\phi^X_{\tilde{t}+t_0}(m)=d[\phi^X_{\tilde{t}}\circ \phi_{t_0}^X](m)=d[\phi_\tilde{t}^X(\phi_{t_0}^X)](m)=d\phi_{\tilde{t}}^X(\phi^X_{t_0}(m))d\phi^X_{t_0}(m),} $$
$$\text{we have:}$$
$$=\frac{d}{d\tilde{t}}\Bigr|_{\tilde{t}=0}(d\phi^X_{\tilde{t}+t_0}(m))^{-1} \space Y(\phi_{\tilde{t}+t_0}^X(m))=\frac{d}{d\tilde{t}}\Bigr|_{\tilde{t}=0}(d\phi_{t_0}^X(m))^{-1}d\phi_{\tilde t}^X(\phi_{t_0}^X(m)) Y(\phi_\tilde{t}^X(\phi_{t_0}^X(m))=$$

$$\text{I've used the fact that: } (AB)^{-1}=B^{-1}A^{-1}. \text{If we now factor out }(d\phi_{t_0}^X(m))^{-1}, \text{we get}:$$

$$ =(d\phi_{t_0}^X(m))^{-1} \frac{d}{d\tilde{t}}\Bigr|_{\tilde{t}=0}d\phi_{\tilde t}^X(\phi_{t_0}^X(m)) Y(\phi_\tilde{t}^X(\phi_{t_0}^X(m))=(d\phi_{t_0}^X(m))^{-1}L_XY(\phi_{t_0}^X(m))=(d\phi_{t_0}^X(m))^{-1}[X,Y](\phi_{t_0}^X(m)).$$

**Bounty** :Could someone please verify that the above derivation (especially the red part) is correct? $d\phi^X_{\tilde{t}+t_0}$ is meant as $d(\phi^X_{\tilde{t}+t_0}(m))$ right?

Comment: Your formula for the derivative of the inverse is missing a negative sign.

Comment: @TedShifrin You're correct! It was a typo, I've added the negative sign.

Comment: Have you established that the Lie bracket is the Lie derivative $\mathscr L_XY$? If so, it seems like you should just factor out $d\phi_{-t_0}$ and reduce to the definition of the Lie derivative at $t=0$. I haven't sat down and written this out, however.

Comment: @Ted Shifrin I understand that the Lie deriative of a vector field is given by the Lie Bracket. However the Lie derivative of Y along X is defined as: $\frac{d}{dt}\Bigr|_{t=0} (d\phi_t^X){^{-1}Y(\phi_t^X)}$, correct? But here we have $t=t_0$. Could you please elaborate on your suggestion. I really appreciate your help.

Comment: Yes, I'm suggesting that you deduce it for $t=0$ first, and then observe that $\phi_{t_0+h} = \phi_{t_0}\circ\phi_h$.

Comment: @TedShifrin For $t=0$ this just gives the lie bracket $[X,Y](m)$, or $[X,Y](\phi_0^X(m))$.

Comment: @TedShifrin You're suggesting I use one of the expressions calculated for $t=0, \phi_{t=0}^X$ and then use $\phi_{t=0}^X=\phi_{t_0-t_0}=\phi_{t_0}\circ\phi_{-t_0}$ But this doesn't get me anywhere either. Could you please be more specific.

Comment: @TedShifrin I've edited my question, it now seems to be okay. I'm just not sure about the red part in the Edit section:

$$d\phi^X_{\tilde{t}+t_0}(m)=d[\phi^X_{\tilde{t}}\circ \phi_{t_0}^X](m)=d[\phi_\tilde{t}^X(\phi_{t_0}^X)](m)=d\phi_{\tilde{t}}^X(\phi^X_{t_0}(m))d\phi^X_{t_0}(m).$$

Does this really hold?

Comment: Is this from a book? Do Carmo perhaps? Where does this question come from?

Comment: @RomainS No, this is not from a book, it's was given as an exercise in our lectures. I think the **Edit** part is ok now, but I'm not completely sure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lemma: If $\gamma: J \to M$ is an integral curve of $X\in \mathfrak{X}(M)$, then $\tilde{\gamma}
 : J - s \to M $ defined by $\tilde{\gamma}(t) = 
(t + s)$ is also an integral curve of $X$.

Proof:

$$\dot{\tilde{
\gamma}}=\frac{d}{d\theta}|_{\theta=t}\gamma(t+s)=\dot{\gamma}(t+s)=X(\gamma(t+s))=X(\tilde{\gamma}(t))$$

To show the red part we need to show that the flow obeys the summing condition. As $t_0$ is in the flow domain $\mathcal{D}^{(m)}$ and it is open, we get that for small enough $t$ is in $\mathcal{D}^{(q)}$ where $q=\phi^X_{t_0}(m)$. We must show that $\phi^X_{t+t_0}(m)=\phi^X_t(q)$.

Writing $\gamma : \mathcal{D}^{(m)} - s \to M$ defined by $\gamma(t) = \phi^X_t(m)(t + t_0)$, the lemma above gives us that is also an integral curve emanating from $q$,
and by uniqueness, we get that
$\gamma(t) = \phi^X_t(q)$. Thus,$\phi^X_{t+t_0}(m)=\phi^X_t(q)=\phi^X_t(\phi^X_{t_0}(m))$.

This shows that we can write $\phi^X_{\tilde{t}+t_0}:\{p\in M|(\tilde{t}+t_0,p)\in \mathcal{D}\}\to M$ as the composition you wrote in the red part. A good reference for this is page 212 of John M. Lee introduction to smooth manifolds.

Comment: This is what I've been looking for.  Thank you!